# Можно ли заставить в C++ коде в vs2008 выполнять vbs скрипт?

Tags: vbscript, c++

Здравствуйте, как можно реализовать выполнение vbs скрипта в студии?

Похоже, это не реально([http://yandex.ru/...](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+vbs+crhbgn+%D0%B2+visual+studio&lr=213)). Так ответил яндекс... А этот сайт заставляет верить что можно: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=347011

Не откажусь от нормального ресурса.

Спасибо.

Comment: Выполнятся в студии или всё же в программах написанных в Visual Studio ?

Comment: В программах, написанных в студии...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А через system() он разве не исполнится ? Или Вы хотите каким-то образом разделять переменные в C++ и VBS ?

Если результаты скрипта выводятся в стандартный вывод, то прочесть их можно, используя popen().

Comment: Такое дело,.. он у меня system-ом открывается, если находится отдельно... Я бы хотел его как-то впихнуть в 1-н исполняемый файл...
(exe+vbs), а vbs запускать из кода, может не кода, ну вообщем из "контейнера".....

Comment: Если скрипт не меняется (или немного меняется) его текст можно хранить в строковых переменных (константах), в общем набить при написании программы.


По ходу выполнения программы можно на его основе сгенерить исполняемы текст скрипта.


 Потом вывести в файл (например в TEMP) и выполнить. Потом файл удалить.

Comment: Если текст не меняется.. то зачем его вообще куда то запихивать ?

@Alerr, зачем выполнять не изменяемый код на vbs ? :)

Comment: Ну, у меня есть скрипт, который я просто хочу выполнить... Неважно зачем(программа в скрипте сложна для перевода в с++).
т.е. AVP, вы хотите сказать, что я могу создать файл и внего вывести всё.. А затем его удалить? Строковые переменные-это вы про string?

Comment: Спасибо, оригинально..

Comment: Я бы набивал в массив static char *script[] = {"line 1", ..., NULL };